# Active Directory secret engine of vault returns "unable to find service account"?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, hashicorp-vault

I am testing vault with Active Directory secret engine. I have a running freeipa server and i created an account for testing. After I wrote the configurations in `ad/config` through vault, I tried to map the account I created to a role in vault through the path `ad/roles/testaccount` and I've put `service_account_name="testaccount"`. Vault then gives me error back saying:

```
Code: 500. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:

* unable to find service account named testaccount in active directory, searches are case sensitive
```

I am not sure what is the problem but I used `ldapsearch` tool to make sure the account I tested with is actually there, and it was.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue, the main problem you might face is that you can't configure the filter to search in ldap. Vault api is fixed to use `userPrincipalName` and this won't work directly for all ldap servers. The way to solve this is by adding a proxy (openldap proxy) and map attributes in `slapd.conf` (after defining them in schema) using `rwm-map` attribute.

See this link for more info : https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/OpenLDAP_as_proxy_to_AD